# Docker/Mariadb: Error starting userland proxy: Listen tcp {IP}:{PORT}: bind cannot assign requested address

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, docker, mariadb, docker-compose

I have been unable to run the command: `docker-compose up --build -d` as I get the following error:

**ERROR: for mariadb  Cannot start service mariadb: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint cdr_performance_tracker_mariadb_1 (c98f1e65cf0226cfd2ea3e5493d8a13eb2dc14d1ea4194cae31f0789090d6172): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 {IP}:{PORT}: bind: cannot assign requested address
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.**

This is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
    app:
        restart: always
        build: ./app
        ports:
            - {IP Where the app is hosted on AWS}:8501:8501
        environment:
            STREAMLIT_DB_HOST: mariadb
            STREAMLIT_DB_NAME: db
            STREAMLIT_DB_USER: username
            STREAMLIT_DB_PASSWORD: password
        depends_on:
            - mariadb
        networks:
            - streamlit_network
        command: streamlit run Main.py
    mariadb:
        image: mariadb:10.5.17
        ports:
            - {IP where MARIADB is hosted}:3306:3306
        volumes:
            - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
            - db_conf:/etc/mysql/conf.d
        environment:
            MARIADB_DATABASE: opsearch
            MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootPassword
        networks:
            - streamlit_network
    nginx:
        restart: always
        build: ./nginx
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        depends_on:
            - app
            - mariadb
volumes:
    db_data:
    db_conf:
networks:
    streamlit_network:
        driver: bridge
~
```

I am running this in an Ubuntu VM on AWS Lightsail. Any pointers on how I can solve this.

Comment: Are `{IP Where the app is hosted on AWS}` and `{IP where MARIADB is hosted}` different?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider yes there are different.

Comment: uhm, why? the containers are started on the same instance. Does the instance have multiple interfaces with different IPs? Or are you trying to run containers on different instances with the same docker-compose.yml?

Comment: I am running multiple containers within the same docker-compose.yml in one single Ubuntu instance. I have this IP address to access MariaDB and I have my static IP address where my app is hosted.